# How to get BIM 360 projects for a user with Forge?

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is there a way to get the BIM 360 projects a user has been assigned to, such as GET projects/:user_id?

Comment: As I know, there is not such API available currently as I know. Maybe you can try to use a combination of `GET projects/:project_id/companies` and `GET accounts/:account_id/users` to map company id with users, then find a user you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

There is another way to archive this with Forge Data Management API and Forge BIM360 API (HQ API), if you don't insist on obtaining projects associated with a user via BIM360 API directly. So, we can use them in this way:

1. Call BIM360 API `GET accounts/:account_id/users` to get user list and extract the `uid` value from the response.
2. Pass the `uid` from the above to request header `x-user-id`, then call Forge DM API `GET hubs/:hub_id/projects` with the 2-legged token

Hope it helps!

========================

A quick update for this question. Unfortunately, this request is not available currently, but we have a plan to support such a function in the future as I know.

In addition, the combination I mentioned above is not a good option. According to our engineering team. Since `GET projects/:project_id/companies` is at the project level, `GET accounts/:account_id/users` is on the account level, and users can also be assigned to a company at project level that is different from its default company at the account level.

So, please ignore it, sorry for a bad suggestion!